# Paper_Trail Showing Diff Between Two Versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, diff, paper-trail-gem

I am new to Rails, but making progress. I'm using RubyMine for this project.

I have Paper_Trail working, saving previous versions of the data "xoi_qb". My view is currently showing the current and previous data as I'd like, but I would like to show the diff between the current version "xoi_qb" and the previous version "xoi_qb". For instance, the current version may be "97" and the previous version may be "94", and I would like to display "XOI +/-: +3". I would like to display this difference and add the "+" or "-" based on the positive or negative change.

In my model, Paper Trail is set to create versions like this:

```
  def get_xoi_qb
    xoi_qb = []
    self.versions.each do |version|
      unless version.reify.nil?
        xoi_qb << version.reify.xoi_qb
      end
    end
    return xoi_qb
  end
```

And in my HTML set to display the versions like this:

```
  <th>Previous XOI</th>
  <table>
    <% @quarterback.versions.each do |version| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= version.reify.xoi_qb %> dated <%= version.created_at %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
```

Not sure how to show the difference between the two. I know the answer is in the "Diffing Versions" section [here](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail), but I can't figure out how to apply it to my issue.

Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<th>Difference</th>
  <table>
    <% number_of_versions = @quarterback.versions.drop(1).count%>
    <% number_of_versions.times do | index | %>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <%= versions[index].reify.try(:xoi_qb).to_i - versions[index + 1].reify.try(:xoi_qb).to_i  %>
          </td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: No, that didn't work unfortunately. I got the error: NameError in Quarterback#show
undefined local variable or method `versions' for #<#<Class:0x007fa914d7ed48>:0x007fa919a8b988>